# Using GitHub for issue tracking for a local Git repository

Tags: github, tortoisegit

My company has a Git repository hosted on our servers. We use TortoiseGit. I would like to integrate it with GitHub Issues.

Is this possible? Note that we do **not** host our repository on GitHub.

I have tried using the bugtraq settings on TortoiseGit but it doesn't interact with the repository I've set up on GitHub.

Comment: What about hosting your own Gitlab server?

Comment: Or Gogs (https://github.com/gogits/gogs), which is pretty clsoe to Github in terms of UI

Comment: That's helpful, thanks - will look into that

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to integrate it with GitHub Issues. Is this possible?

*Integrate* in this context is a very open concept. Which integrations are you looking for? If you're not hosting the code on the repository itself, any kind of integration will be hard, but it really depends on your specific goal with GitHub Issues and which kind of *triggers* and *links* you want from your code to your issues.

From experience if I assume that by integration you mean linking Git commits in your local repository to GitHub Issues the clear answer is no.

So if you really want to use GitHub Issues without pushing the Git code upstream, have you considered creating an empty project to just use GitHub Issues and GitHub [Projects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6MGKHkNtxU). You won't be able to reference issues from the commit message, i.e., `Fixed issue found in #4` but you can use it as a standalone project management tool.

[Trello offers a free tier](https://trello.com/pricing) for project management that you might also want to check out.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was hoping I would be able to make a commit on TortoiseGit, and then do as you say - write something like "Fixed #4", which would then close issue #4 on the GitHub repository. That definitely is not possible? I just found [this](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) page. Is it possible to use webhooks to integrate with TortoiseGit?

Apologies if this is a dumb question - I am quite new to this. Appreciate your help.